# Need the original Wordpress functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I messed up the `functions.php` file on my Wordpress website, and I cannot find the original code anywhere... So instead of reinstalling Wordpress (simply changing theme won't work) maybe someone here has it?

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running?

Comment: Are you talking about the theme's functions.php file? If so, you could just redownload it from wherever you got it / bought it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the answer to that problem- `function.php` file is part of the theme, so when I simply download the WP files again I won't find it there (unless the theme is the default). So the way to solve this is simply to delete the theme and download it again. Then everything will return to normal. Same goes for the other files in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Just download WordPress.. unzip it any location to get the fle ..

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has their Git repo here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress

Your `functions.php` file can be found here, assuming there have been no changes since the version you're on: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php

Answer (score 1):

First check your wordpress version and download the appropriate ***functions.php*** files from below link

https://wordpress.org/download/releases/

Your can check your wordpress version in

- Admin Dashboard Page
- Generator tag in source code ( Use ctrl + u )
- Check readme.html in the root directory